# pandas insert values in order plus one

Tags: python, pandas, sequence

I want to make a data frame with columns from 2012 to 2100. I would like to make a data frame that gives +1 in 2012 in reference column Stand_Age(example below table), and +1 in 2013 plus +1 in 2012 and +1 in 2100 in 2099 as well. Code and the frame are below.

```
for i in list(range(0, 90, 1)):
    Stand_Age[i+1] = Stand_Age[i] + 1
```

[image: pre year plus one by 2100]

Comment: Please explain your requirement better. What do you mean by "X to Y in the next year"? What does "the next year" mean exactly? Can you provide a required result?

Comment: I added exlpaniation. Thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't use `Stand_Age[i+1]` but rather `df["2012"] = df["Stand_Age"] + 1` and probably `df[str(2011+i)] = df["Stand_Age"] + i` with `range(1, 90)` instead of `range(0, 90)`

Comment: shorter `for i in range(90):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Stand_Age[i+1]` but rather

```
df["2012"] = df["Stand_Age"] + 1
```

And for many rows it would need

```
for i in range(1, 90):
    df[str(2011+i)] = df["Stand_Age"] + i
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Stand_Age": [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
})

print(df)

for i in range(1, 10):
    df[str(2011+i)] = df["Stand_Age"] + i

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  Stand_Age
0          1
1          1
2          2
3          2
4          3
5          3
6          4
7          4
8          5
9          5

   Stand_Age  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019  2020
0          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
1          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
2          2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11
3          2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11
4          3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
5          3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
6          4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
7          4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
8          5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
9          5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
```